# MySQL - Optimize JOIN only grouping necessary rows

Tags: mysql

My query selects the maximum value of a second table (laboratory values) for a subset of cases. Obviously this method is extremely slow (>25seconds) as I am using a subquery that, not knowing parent's filter, groups all laboratory.CaseID (15k in a 10mil record table) before just using 10 of them. The problem is easy to see in an EXPLAIN.

```
SELECT cases.CaseID,t.val FROM cases 
  LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT Max(laboratory.LaboratoryValue) as val , CaseID FROM laboratory 
    WHERE laboratory.LaboratoryID =682 
    GROUP by laboratory.CaseID) as t 
  ON t.CaseID = cases.CaseID 
WHERE cases.Diagnosis = 16;
```

I tried to optimize the query using a TEMPORARY TABLE, which speeds up to 0,008s, but this method seems a bit clumsy when doing it to many fields.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptest
    SELECT cases.CaseID FROM cases WHERE cases.Diagnosis = 16;
SELECT cases.CaseID,t.val FROM cases 
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT Max(laboratory.LaboratoryValue) as val , CaseID FROM laboratory 
   WHERE laboratory.LaboratoryID =682
     AND laboratory.CaseID IN (SELECT CaseID FROM tmptest) 
   GROUP by laboratory.CaseID) as t 
  ON t.CaseID = cases.CaseID 
WHERE cases.Diagnosis = 16;
```

Is there a simpler solution for query optimization?

As requested the EXPLAIN. It shows the problem, CaseID is (as expected) not used.
[image]

The second query does it right (NoDoubles contains both indexes);

[image]

Comment: `WHERE laboratory.LaboratoryID =682 AND laboratory.CaseID < 10` in subquery - anycase the rows which not matched `laboratory.CaseID < 10` will be removed in outer query... Also think does `LaboratoryID=682` is correct in outer query's WHERE.

Comment: Thanks, simplified the query too much, corrected it. The WHERE clause field is not contained in subquery table so I cannot add it to subquery.

Comment: See if removing "LEFT" speeds it up.

Comment: How many rows in each of the two tables?  10M in `laboratory`?  How many in `cases`?

Comment: Please show us the Explain.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Added the EXPLAIN of both queries. As expected the first query calculates all rows, the second using a CaseID filter has an easy job

Answer (score 0):

These indexes are needed:

```
laboratory: INDEX(LaboratoryID, CaseID, LaboratoryValue)
cases:      INDEX(Diagnosis, CaseID)
```

Two more formulations to try and time:

```
SELECT  c.CaseID, L.val
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  CaseID, Max(laboratory.LaboratoryValue) as val
            FROM  laboratory
            WHERE  laboratory.LaboratoryID = 682
            GROUP by  laboratory.CaseID 
        ) AS L
    JOIN  cases AS c USING(CaseID)
    WHERE  c.Diagnosis = 16;

SELECT  c.CaseID, 
        ( SELECT  Max(laboratory.LaboratoryValue)
            FROM  laboratory
            WHERE  laboratory.LaboratoryID = 682
              AND  CaseID = c.CaseID 
        ) AS val
    FROM  cases AS c
    WHERE  c.Diagnosis = 16;
```

They are not identical because of "LEFT".  So, verify that you get the "right" answers.  The first uses `JOIN`; the second is equivalent to your `LEFT JOIN`.

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN` for whatever formulations you want to discuss.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.